# Class Exits in Try/Catch on NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, junit, try-catch

I wan't to try to load a class and if this class can't be loaded to continue my program.

```
protected void checkClass(){
        classChecked = false;
        try {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Class<?> compiledClass = cl.loadClass(sTestclass); // << EXCEPTIOn lINE
            cRun = compiledClass;           
        classChecked = true;    
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("- Testclass not found!");
            System.err.println("- Make sure you typed the package name\n and the Class name correctly!");
        }       
    }
```

But instead the whole progam exits with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: data/testcases/comman
do/ctest (wrong name: data/testcases/commando/CTest)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
1)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at cmd.TwCmd.checkClass(TwCmd.java:214)
        at cmd.TwCmd.askForTestcase(TwCmd.java:107)
        at cmd.TwCmd.anotherTestcase(TwCmd.java:146)
        at cmd.TwCmd.executeInteractiveTw(TwCmd.java:85)
        at cmd.TwCmd.runThrough(TwCmd.java:60)
        at cmd.TwCmd.main(TwCmd.java:260)
```

I already surrounded it with `Try/Catch` but still the whole program exits on this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see an `Error`, not an `Exception`. Catch the `NoClassDefFoundError` and you should be able handle it in a catch block and continue.

(`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is not a subclass of `java.lang.Exception`)

Answer (score 9):

[`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is not an `Exception`, it derives from `Error`.

Try catching `Throwable` if you want to catch them all.